# Перевод из byte в long java

Tags: java, byte

вот метод

```
byte [] bytes = { 0, 6, 36, -84, 113, 125, -118, -47 };
    System.out.println(ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).getLong());
```

вывод:

```
1729172917291729
```

почему ответ именно такой? откуда появляются такие числа?

Comment: Ответ на ваш вопрос кроется в ответе на другой вопрос: каков размер переменной long в байтах?

Comment: точно так же, как из списка "1, 2, 3" получается число "123". Или "321", смотря, с какой стороны в списке старший разряд.

Answer (score 2):

Это не числа. Это число, одно. Long - это 8 байт. В буфер вы передали 8 байт и получили на выходе одно число, полученное от объединения байт.

Вот рассмотрим например байты. 1, 2, 3, 4. В двоичном виде это будет 00000001, 00000010, 00000011, 00000100. С помощью ByteBuffer объединяются они в одно целое:

```
00000001, 00000010, 00000011, 00000100 = 00000001000000100000001100000100
```

В десятичном виде это будет число 16909060. Так и у вас. Только вы взяли 8 байт, и объединили их в одно число типа long.

Не забывайте, что компьютер работает только с двоичными числами.

Если вам нужно каждый байт преобразовать к long, то нужно обойти каждое число в цикле. И обратите внимание, если будете пользоваться обычным cast типа `(long) -1234`, то будет сохраняться десятичное представление, если вашим способом - двоичное. Это происходит из-за того, что один бит (самый старший) используется для хранения знака.

Comment: т.е. вот эти числа 0, 6, 36, -84, 113, 125, -118, -47 просто представляются в двоичном виде и объединяются в 1 8-ми байтовый long?

Comment: Да, это происходит за счет использования ByteBuffer. Если бы вы каждое по отдельности число перевели в Long, такого бы не наблюдалось.

Comment: а можно уточнить,почему если дополнительно добавлять байты например 0, 6, 36, -84, 113, 125, -118, -47,56,22 ,вывод у нас не изменяется,например если в калькуляторе вручную считать,результат будет другой

Comment: Потому что вы добавили еще два байта, получили всего 10 байт. Когда вы вызывали метод getLong, вы взяли первые 8 байт (long в java это всегда 8, также как Int = 4, а byte = 1), и интерпретировали их как одно число. А остальные 2 байта у вас так и остались в буфере. Просто представте ByteBuffer как конвеер с байтами, а методы get****() забирают из конвеера определенное количество байт и интерпретируют соостветсвующим образом.